# How to split a string on a given pattern while including the pattern to the second part of the split string

Tags: php

I have a string which has to be split into multiple shorter strings. The delimiters on which the string should be split are given, however I would like to include them in the string that comes after the delimiter on which the original string should be split. For example. This is the string:

```
$string = "8 UUR Dit is een test voor 8 uur 9 UUR Dit is een test voor 9 uur 10 UUR Dit is een test voor 10 uur 11 UUR Dit is een test voor 11 uur 12 UUR Dit is een test voor 12 uur 13 UUR Dit is een test voor 13 uur 14 UUR Dit is een test voor 14 uur 15 UUR Dit is een test voor 15 uur";
```

And it should be split like so:

```
$strings[0] = 8 UUR Dit is een test voor 8 uur;
$strings[1] = 9 UUR Dit is een test voor 9 uur;
$strings[2] = 10 UUR Dit is een test voor 10 uur;
...
```

so the first two words (8 UUR, 9 UUR, 10 UUR, ...) are a delimiter, whatever comes after can differ. How can I split the string on these recurring words while including them on the second part of the original string that is being split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve it with `preg_split` and positive lookahead.

```
$strings = preg_split('| (?=\d{1,} UUR)|', $string);
```

This produces the following array:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => string '8 UUR Dit is een test voor 8 uur' (length=32)
  1 => string '9 UUR Dit is een test voor 9 uur' (length=32)
  2 => string '10 UUR Dit is een test voor 10 uur' (length=34)
  3 => string '11 UUR Dit is een test voor 11 uur' (length=34)
  4 => string '12 UUR Dit is een test voor 12 uur' (length=34)
  5 => string '13 UUR Dit is een test voor 13 uur' (length=34)
  6 => string '14 UUR Dit is een test voor 14 uur' (length=34)
  7 => string '15 UUR Dit is een test voor 15 uur' (length=34)
```

Because the positive lookahead would split on a single digit I used space as additional separator. In your desired outcome it was not clear what to do with the spaces in front or back of the string.

The explanation: The lookahead tells regex to split the string by space character ,which is followed by "1 or more digits followed by space followed by UUR"